# Possible counterexample to a theorem assuming Lang's conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, counterexamples

Looks like I found a counterexample to a theorem assuming Lang's conjecture,
but not sure it is correct.

[Boundedness of Mordell–Weil ranks of certain elliptic curves and Lang’s conjecture](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X02001269/pdfft?md5=2957cb5b184468b72aeac1c0c38ed739&pid=1-s2.0-S0022314X02001269-main.pdf)
 p. 2

**Theorem 1.3**. Let $K$ be a finitely generated field over $\mathbf{Q}$.
Let $n \ge 8$ be an integer and let
$\alpha_i, (i=0,\ldots,n)$ be fixed elements of $K$. 
Suppose Conjecture 1.2 holds for $k$ a finitely
generated field over $\mathbf{Q}$ (cf. [2]). 
Then there are only finitely many elliptic curves of the
form $y^2=a x^4 + b x^2 +c \; (a,b,c \in K)$ which have 
$\alpha_i$ as the $x$-coordinates of some
$K$-rational points. 
In particular the Mordell–Weil ranks of such elliptic curves are
bounded.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{21}], a=c=\frac{-\frac{112}{75} s^{4} + \frac{6647}{4725} s^{2} - \frac{83521}{33339600}}{s^{2}}
,b=\frac{\frac{1799}{75} s^{4} - \frac{171377}{37800} s^{2} + \frac{21464897}{533433600}}{s^{2}}, s \in K$.

Let $P(x)=a x^4 + b x^2 + a$. The discriminant depends on $s$ and $P(x)=P(-x)$.

Consider the elliptic curve $y^2=P(x)$ for $s$ for which the discriminant
doesn't vanish.

Let $n=9$ and $\alpha_i=\{1,2,4,1/2,1/4,-1,-2,-4,-1/2,-1/4\}$

$$P(1)= \left(21\right) \cdot s^{-2} \cdot (s - \frac{17}{84})^{2} \cdot (s + \frac{17}{84})^{2}$$
$$P(2)= \left(\frac{1764}{25}\right) \cdot s^{-2} \cdot (s^{2} + \frac{289}{7056})^{2}$$
$$P(4)= 289$$
$$P(1/2)= \left(\frac{441}{100}\right) \cdot s^{-2} \cdot (s^{2} + \frac{289}{7056})^{2}$$
$$P(1/4)= 289/256$$

All of the above are squares as are $P(-x)$.

For all infinitely many admissible choices of $s$, $\alpha_i$
are $x$-coordinates.

The $j$ invariant of the Jacobian depends on $s$.

> Is this really a counterexample to **Theorem 1.3**?

$a,b$ in machine readable form:

```
 a=c=-1/33339600*(289+7056*s^2)^2/s^2+289/189
 b=257/533433600*(289+7056*s^2)^2/s^2-4913/756
```

Comment: Of course, if this is a counterexample to Theorem 1.3, then the most likely explanation is that there's an error in the proof of Theorem 1.3 and the condition $n\ge8$ needs to be replaced with $n\ge9$ or $n\ge10$. It's much less likely that this would contradict the Bombieri-Lang conjecture. But still, you've found a nice example. (Hmmm... Another possibility is that Theorem 1.3 is misstated and actually only holds on a Zariski open subset of the parameter space, which would allow for a finite number of families of exceptions.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, this is a counterexample to Theorem 1.3.  But it looks like the issue is with the proof of Theorem 1.3, and is not relevant to Lang's conjecture.  Namely, your example contradicts Theorem 4.2 of that paper, which does not rely on Lang's conjecture.  Then the proof of Theorem 1.3 relies on Theorem 4.2, in addition to relying on Lang's conjecture.  The only proof given for Theorem 4.2 is "by the argument in [4], we obtain the following theorem", so it is not completely surprising if an error occurs there.

**Added later:** In fact, the problem is that the author needed to assume that $\alpha_i^2\ne\alpha_j^2$ for $i\ne j$, rather than just that $\alpha_i\ne\alpha_j$.  Otherwise everything he says about $W_n$ is wrong.  Namely, given elements $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ of a number field $K$, he defines $W_n$ to be the subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n$ defined by the equations
$$ \left| \begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&1&1 \\
\alpha_0^2&\alpha_1^2&\alpha_2^2&\alpha_i^2 \\
\alpha_0^4&\alpha_1^4&\alpha_2^4&\alpha_i^4 \\
Y_0 & Y_1 & Y_2&Y_i \end{array} \right| = 0\,\,\,(i=3,4,\dots,n).
$$
Theorem 4.2 asserts that if $n\ge 8$ then the only curves on $W_n$ of genus $0$ or $1$ are the lines
$$
(Y_0,\dots,Y_9)=\bigl(\pm(s+t\alpha_0^2),\pm(s+t\alpha_1^2),\dots,\pm(s+t\alpha_n)^2\bigr).$$
Of course, your example produces further genus-$0$ curves on $W_9$, and hence contradicts Theorem 4.2.  But as I said, the real issue is that the author should have assumed that the $\alpha_i^2$ are pairwise distinct, since otherwise everything he says about $W_n$ is wrong.

Comment: Thank you. So adding $\alpha_i^2\ne\alpha_j^2$ probably makes the paper correct?

Comment: That's what I would guess, but I didn't check all the proofs (mainly I didn't check the ones which rely on carrying over arguments from Vojta's paper).

Comment: At some point, I did check it (including Vojta's paper) and indeed, one just want evaluate the quadrics az^2+bz+c at 8 given points. In this paper, the 8 points are the squares of the alphas.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  The result of this paper is neat, so I'm happy to hear that someone can vouch for it (after the slight modification).

Comment: The paper claim the rank is bounded. According to [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164629/argument-for-unboundedness-of-integral-points-of-elliptic-curves-over-number-fie) the rank can be arbitrary large depending of the degree, isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: This might not apply to the specific curves in the paper, but in the linked question both answers and comment claim the rank can be unbounded in certain number fields. The number of integral points is unbounded and it is claimed the points are linearly independent.

Comment: @Pasten Are 8 points enough? As I read it the points are indexed from 0, so n=8 means 9 points. 8 points are possible IMO.

Comment: @joro: You're right on both counts. That paper asserts uniform boundedness of Mordell-Weil ranks but doesn't prove it, and in fact such uniform boundedness is clearly false: just pick any elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ and let $K$ be the number field generated by the coordinates of $r$ non-torsion points in $E(\overline{\mathbf{Q}})$ which are $\mathbf{Z}$-linearly independent from one another, then $E/K$ has rank at least $r$.  And for your most recent comment, yes, the main result must be modified to require that the values $\alpha_i^2$ are pairwise distinct for $0\le i\le 8$.

Comment: I wish there were a database about bugs in papers.

Comment: The closest to such a thing is Math.Reviews (although they always say that journals are responsible for this, rather than them -- but then apparently nobody is responsible for bugs in papers published in conference proceedings).  Anyway just now I emailed Math.Reviews pointing out the mistakes in the paper, they will give the reviewer the option to revise his review in light of my remarks.  I also emailed the editor who handled this paper; based on prior experience, I'm certain that he will proceed with the greatest professionalism.

Comment: Zieve, is it true that similar rational parametrization with the additional constraint will imply another mistake in the paper? What about curves resulting from points on genus $1$ curve?

Comment: @joro: Yes, genus 0 curves on $W_n$ are the same thing as rational parametrizations like yours.  But my guess is that there won't be counterexamples under the further constraint: although the paper is not carefully written, it looks like it contains enough ideas to imply the modified conclusion (although I didn't check the details).

Comment: Zieve, the way I read it $a,b,c$ can be chosen freely, allowing isomorphic curves. Is this true?

Comment: @Pasten If X is the x coordinate of F(X)=y^2 it is also on u^2*F(X)=(u*y)^2 for infinitely many u? Are there other hypothesis missing?

Comment: @joro It's been a long time, but what I remember is that the application of the Bombieri-Lang conjecture is on the varieties $W_n$, and projectivization should account for this. In any case, there are several detail missing in this paper as the author refers to Vojta's work at several crucial points of the argument, but Vojta considered a slightly different problem.