# Mordell-Weil rank of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1},\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},...)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

It is known that the group of $K$-rational points of an elliptic curve $E$ is finitely generated if $K$ is a number field of finite degree over $\mathbb{Q}$.
The picture is less clear if $K$ is infinite-dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I believe the best result is that of Kobayashi who proved (modulo the usual conjectures on Hasse-Weil $L$-functions and BSD) that $\operatorname{rank}(E(\mathbb{Q}^{\operatorname{ab}}))=\infty$.

What is known about the rank of $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1},\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},...)$?

EDIT: I have a follow-up question that is more precise:
[Is there an infinite family of primes $q_{1},q_{2},...$ so that the rank of $E(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-q_{i}}))$ equals that of $E(\mathbb{Q})$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244230/is-there-an-infinite-family-of-primes-q-1-q-2-so-that-the-rank-of-e)

Comment: If I recall correctly, there was something a bit like this in Drew Sutherland's talk at the recent Cremona birthday conference, notes available here: https://math.mit.edu/~drew/Cremona60.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answers and comments in [Argument for unboundedness of integral points of elliptic curves over number fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164629/argument-for-unboundedness-of-integral-points-of-elliptic-curves-over-number-fie) show the rank is unbounded in *finite* extensions of the rationals and in infinite extensions it is infinite.

Basically the question takes $f(x)=y^2$ and takes points $x,\sqrt{f(x)}$, giving example.

JSE's answer shows linear independence of the example, which scales infinitely as far as I can tell.

JSE's comment about unboundedness of rank in number fields:

> It should do. Just take your r points defined over disjoint quadratic fields, whose compositum is K; the MW rank over THAT field is finite, so you can certainly choose an integer x such that (sqrt(f(x))) generates a further quadratic extension of K, then you have rank r+1 and you just keep going. – JSE Apr 28 '14 at 17:33

Comment: The first sentence is a bit misleading. There are plenty of infinite extensions where the curve has still finite rank. Even among the composites of quadratic extensions.

Answer (score 2):

The rank is probably unbounded. If you can arrange for the quadratic twist $E_d$ of $E$ to have positive rank (e.g. by making the sign of the functional equation be $-1$ and assuming BSD) then $E$ has a point of infinite order in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ and, by doing that for infinitely many $d$, you get infinite rank over your field.

Comment: "and, by doing that for infinitely many $d$, you get infinite rank over your field." Can you elaborate a bit on this, please?

Comment: Actually, I would think that this is proven. Anayltic methods should give a large density of negative $d$ for which the twist vanishes to order $1$. Then Heegner point constructions should yield a new point of infinite order.

Comment: @TimoKeller If the set of points generated by these points of infinite order (each one in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d})\setminus\Bbb Q$ for distinct primes (say) $d$) were finitely generated, then all the generators would be elements of a single finite extension of $\Bbb Q$, which would imply that a finite extension contains infinitely many square roots of primes, which isn't the case.